# Disable Message Windows

Tags: scripting

Is there any way to disable Mathematica's internal popup windows, such as "Why the beep?"

Cannot seem to find any documentation on the ability to turn it off, but need it turned off to write some automations.

Comment: I have figured it out, will leave this post up for reference, by feel free to remove it: Format->OptionInpsector->GlobalOptions->MessageOptions->ErrorAction and set ErrorAction off of DialogBox to remove the window.

Comment: This seems to be a valid answer to your question. It is common and welcomed on this site to answer your own question, so I would suggest to make your comment an answer. If you expect that someone could have a good alternative answer, you might wait a day or so before answering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop up windows can be disabled through the Mathematica drop down window: Format->OptionInpsector->GlobalOptions->MessageOptions->ErrorAction and remove "DialogBox" as an option from ErrorAction to prevent the windows from popping up.